# Sexy Forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, plugins, builder

I stumbled across a page describing a plugin - semantic_form_builder (the blog entry was titled "sexy forms").  The plugin was written by Glenn Gillen, with rubypond.  Anyhow, when I tried to install the plugin, I got some messages indicating that some of the rake tasks were "deprecated", so I'm guessing the issue is due to the fact I'm using Rails 3 & this was written for an earlier version.  Anyone know if this has been updated, converted into a gem or something along those lines?

Comment: Just fyi, the popular gems for forms are [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) and [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). My personal preference is with simple_form. Also, if you are referring to [semantic_form_builder](https://github.com/rubypond/semantic_form_builder) note that it has not been updated since 2008!

Comment: Yeah - that's the one... I noticed the date after I started having problems.  I tend to leap before looking when learning new stuff (like rails - my first app).  I was hoping that I was just missing something or not looking in the right place...  What do you like about simple_form - I'll check it out

Comment: I like the fact that it is so flexible. The tagline is "Forms made easy for Rails! It's tied to a simple DSL, **with no opinion on markup**". See this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form).

Comment: I think we have a winner here -- Thanks Zabba!

Comment: Not sure if you're going to see this but, I'm converting some of my forms & I'm having a hard time figuring out how to convert this one:<% simple_form_for :topic, :url => forum_topics_path do |t| %>
<%= t.input :name, :label => 'Topic' %></p>  <-- it's sort of an embedded form -- is this possible with simple_form ?

  <p>First Post:<br/></p> <--- this is where i start having problems
  <p>Title:</br/><%= text_field :post, :title %></p>
  <p><%= text_area :post, :body %></p>
<%= t.submit 'Save' %>

Comment: I'll see this because SO is smart enough to send me a notification when I'm the only one involved in a question's comment.
But the proper way to get someone's attention would be to use "@" in front of the user's name; so "@Zabba" will cause me
to get a notification in cases where I am not the only participant. Also, it is difficult to read the code of the problem you are facing. Try posting that as a separate question, because it is in fact
a different question.